# Using links from link lists in content editor webpart

Tags: content-editor-web-part, links-list

Is there any way to use link item from link list in CEWP.
I have some link which appear on different web part pages in CEWP.
URL will change some times in the future.
I would like to have it as link in links-list and change URL just once in this item instead of changing manualy on every page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your CEWP is doing but a content editor is typically just a blob of HTML and won't be globally updated.  If you items are in a list, you can drop the list on other pages and when you update your core list, the results will distribute down to the list view web parts on the pages.

Or if you want to manipulate the way your links appear, you can use the new Content Search Web Part, which is similar to a CQWP from 2010 but better!  :)

Comment: Yes, I have plain html in CEWP, linking to some graphics and pages in same sharepoint site.

I was hoping I can use something like:

/sites/some_site/Lists/Links/AllItems.aspx?ID=1&colum=URL

to get a value of LinkItem URL column.

Comment: I'm confused to what your end goal is. Are you saying you just want to extract a single link from your link's list and reference it in plain HTML?